# Extreme points of infinity norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

I have the following problem:

$$\max\{x^TQx \colon \lVert x \rVert_{\infty} = 1\},$$ where $Q$ is positive semidefinite.

I know that $Q$ PSD implies the function is convex. And that norms are convex so this is a convex maximisation problem. Thus there is at least one maximiser and it is an extreme point of the constraint set.

What are the extreme points of this set, for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?